# Create a shortcut in BRACKETS to execute HTML files in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, shortcut, execute, adobe-brackets

I've been struggling to find out a solution with a Bracket extension or whatever to create :

--> a shortcut in Brackets to execute HTML files through Firefox.

I usually use Sublim text, and I created a simple "Build System" to open the html file in Firefox when I strike cmd + B. But I can't find the equivalent with Brackets

(In Sublim text, I used :

```
{
    "cmd": ["open", "-a", "Firefox", "$file"]
}
```

)

I hope I've searched enough before asking this question! Thanks !